# How to remove double scrollbar

Tags: html, css

I'm using Blazor Server and Blazorise UI component library so some of the classes may look a bit funky, but see the attached picture of what's happening. I have two scrollbars on this page. This component sits inside a main layout component, but there's no other html surrounding it so it's on its own. I've tried getting rid of `overflow-x: hidden` on site.css to `overflow:hidden`, but that prevents me from scrolling in total.

html:

```
<div id="mountainTheme">
    <Layout Sider="true">
        <LayoutSider>
            <LayoutSiderContent>
                <h1 class="display-4 text-white">Business Name</h1>
                <hr />
                <Bar Class="mt-5" Mode="BarMode.VerticalInline" Breakpoint="Breakpoint.Desktop"
                     NavigationBreakpoint="Breakpoint.Tablet"
                     CollapseMode="BarCollapseMode.Small">
                    <BarMenu>
                        <BarStart>
                            <BarLink Class="text-white pointer" @onclick="@(() => CallJS("aboutUs"))">About Us</BarLink>
                            <BarLink Class="text-white pointer" @onclick="@(() => CallJS("team"))">Our Team</BarLink>
                            <BarLink Class="text-white pointer" To="#aboutUs">Videos</BarLink>
                            <BarLink Class="text-white pointer" To="#aboutUs">Blogs</BarLink>
                            <BarLink Class="text-white pointer" To="#aboutUs">Pictures</BarLink>
                            <BarLink Class="text-white pointer" To="#aboutUs">Downloads</BarLink>
                            <BarLink Class="text-white pointer" To="#aboutUs">Reviews &amp; Ratings</BarLink>
                            <BarLink Class="text-white pointer" To="#aboutUs">Subscription Plans</BarLink>
                        </BarStart>
                    </BarMenu>
                </Bar>
            </LayoutSiderContent>
        </LayoutSider>
        <Layout>
            <LayoutContent>
                <div class="hero">
                    <h1 class="display-4 text-white">Header Text</h1>
                    <p class="lead mt-2 text-white">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</p>
                    <button class="btn btn-lg btn-danger mt-5">Subscribe Now</button>
                </div>
                <section id="aboutUs">
                    <div class="container text-white pb-5">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-6 offset-3 text-center">
                                <h1 class="display-4">About Us</h1>
                                <hr />
                                <p class="lead">
                                    It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page
                                    when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal
                                    distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here',
                                    making it look like readable English.
                                </p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </section>
                <section id="team">
                    <div class="container text-white pb-5">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-6 offset-3 text-center">
                                <h1 class="display-4">Our Team</h1>
                                <hr />
                                <p class="lead">
                                    It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page
                                    when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal
                                    distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here',
                                    making it look like readable English.
                                </p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </section>
            </LayoutContent>
        </Layout>
    </Layout>
</div>
```

component styles:

```
<style>
    #mountainTheme {
        background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2)), url('./images/pexels-sagui-andrea-618833.jpg');
        background-position: center center;
        background-size: cover;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        height: 100%;
    }

    #mountainTheme .b-layout-sider {
        background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4) !important;
        color: white !important;
        padding: 1rem;
        width: 18rem;
        display: block;
    }

    #mountainTheme .hero {
        text-align: center;
        margin-top: 15%;
        height: 75vh;
    }

    #mountainTheme .b-bar-vertical-inline {
        background-color: transparent !important;
        color: white !important;
        box-shadow: none !important;
    }

</style>
```

site.css

```
html, body {
    font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    min-height: 100%;
    height: auto;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

header {
    box-shadow: 0 2px 4px 0 rgb(0 0 0 / 10%);
}

a, .btn-link {
    color: #0366d6;
}

.btn-primary {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #1b6ec2;
    border-color: #1861ac;
}

.btn-danger {
    background: #d32f2f !important;
    border-color: #d32f2f !important;
}

.text-danger {
    color: #d32f2f !important;
}

.content {
    padding-top: 1.1rem;
}

.valid.modified:not([type=checkbox]) {
    outline: 1px solid #26b050;
}

.invalid {
    outline: 1px solid red;
}

.validation-message {
    color: red;
}

#blazor-error-ui {
    background: lightyellow;
    bottom: 0;
    box-shadow: 0 -1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    display: none;
    left: 0;
    padding: 0.6rem 1.25rem 0.7rem 1.25rem;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 1000;
}

    #blazor-error-ui .dismiss {
        cursor: pointer;
        position: absolute;
        right: 0.75rem;
        top: 0.5rem;
    }

.checkmark-list {
    list-style: none;
}

.checkmark-list li:before {
    content: '✓';
}

.b-layout-sider {
    background: #222222 !important;
    color: white !important;
    padding: 1rem;
    width: 18rem;
    display: block;
}

.accordion .card-header {
    padding: 0;
}

.pointer:hover {
    cursor: pointer !important;
}
```

[image]

Comment: are you trying to remove the first scroll bar? (the short one/first one from the left)

Comment: yes. I just want one main scrollbar.